# Referencing value from Excel Listbox item in .Match function in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I am hoping to use the string value of a selected Listbox item in a .Match function within VBA - I need the the value '1' to be entered into the row where the value of the selection matches a value in column "A:A", on a specific column.

What I thought I would be able to do is to use a .value argument for the selected ListBox item, however this seems to either error out or give me a Boolean response, which isn't what I am after (I am after the actual string value of the item).

I have already looped through all items to set the Selected argument to True, and then I am looping through the list one by one to add '1' to the correct range.

Here is the code I thought would work (but doesn't, it throws an error of "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch" which is presumably down to the .Value not being a String.

```
For x = 0 To Me.CreditsEmployeesListBox.ListCount - 1
Me.CreditsEmployeesListBox.Selected(x) = True
Next

For i = 0 To Me.CreditsEmployeesListBox.ListCount - 1
If Me.CreditsEmployeesListBox.Selected(i) = True Then
    employeeRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.CreditsEmployeesListBox(i).Value, IndexSheet.Range("A:A"), 0)
    IndexSheet.Range(Cells(employeeRow, showCodeColumn).Address).Value = 1
End If
Next
```

It errors out on the 'employeeRow = ...' line. Here, I am essentially trying to ask it:

```
employeeRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(<value of the currently referenced ListBox item>,IndexSheet.Range("A:A"),0)
```

Is this possible with VBA or am I going about this the wrong way?

Thanks
Matt

Comment: If the value currently being referenced by the match is not found it will through the error and stop the code.  Use `Application` instead of `WorksheetFunction`.  You will need to declare `employeeRow` as a variant inside the loop.  Then you will need to test whether it is an error before assigning the value:`IF not IsError(employeeRow) then`

Comment: @ScottCraner `If Not IsError(...`? I am sure that is a typo and you tried to write `If IsNumeric(...` ;)

Comment: @DirkReichel either will work.  But, yes yours is less typing and a little more logical.

Comment: @mhurstsmith just change `Me.CreditsEmployeesListBox(i).Value` to `Me.CreditsEmployeesListBox.List(i)`

Comment: @DirkReichel That is the solution!! Thank you so much! I have been banging my head against this problem for way too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an "hybrid" answer (as there is more than one problem) try this:

```
For x = 0 To Me.CreditsEmployeesListBox.ListCount - 1
  Me.CreditsEmployeesListBox.Selected(x) = True
Next

Dim employeeRow As Variant
For i = 0 To Me.CreditsEmployeesListBox.ListCount - 1
  If Me.CreditsEmployeesListBox.Selected(i) = True Then
    employeeRow = Application.Match(Me.CreditsEmployeesListBox.List(i), IndexSheet.Columns(1), 0)
    If IsNumeric(employeeRow) Then IndexSheet.Cells(employeeRow, showCodeColumn).Value = 1
  End If
Next
```

This also should avoid VBA-errors.

If any questions are left, just ask :)

Comment: Thanks Dirk, having simply added 'CreditsEmployeesListBox.List(i)' to get the string value of the listbox item has done the trick. As for the IsNumeric error catching, the entries in the listbox are populated from the IndexSheet itself, so there will always be a row number attributable to the item. But thanks nonetheless!